# Connecting to MySQL behind NAT without port forwarding

Tags: mysql, nat, remote-access

My situation is as follows:

At work there is a simple network installed by employer: all PCs are connected to one switch, which is connected to router and Internet. The employer **refuses** to set port forwarding. I have a computer on that network on which I have installed MySql server. The server **must** be accessible from work LAN.

So the question is: how can I access MySql from home. I can technically install any software on work PC. I don't want to connect with teamviewer or similar, but rather connect directly to the server with front end application (e.g MS Access)

In worst case I can even install second NIC on the PC which I could get totally another Internet, but I don't even know if it would help and it would be the last resort.

What are my options?

Comment: Can your employer install VPN ? That is a more secure way for the employer to provide access for remote users.

Comment: The whole point is that he does not want to install/change anything. On the other hand I can do basically everything on "my" PC on their network. Can I install VPN? If yes, would it not interfere with access to internal LAN?

Comment: Strange - If your employer needs you to work remotely, they should provide the facilities.  I do this for my own clients.